# modify jQuery.data()

Tags: jquery, jquery-1.4

Let's say I have a bunch of [jQuery's `.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) set for an HTML element like so:

```
$("#my_element").data("myData", {
    data1: myData1,
    data2: myData2,
    data3: myData3
});
```

Now let's say I want to modify the value of `data2` to be `myData2Changed`. How do I modify just this data for my element without having to rewrite the same code above with all the other data?

Comment: change it's value... it's reference, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$.data` stores objects by reference.

Therefore, you can simply modify the object in-place:

```
$(...).data('myData').data2 = whatever;
```

Answer (score -1):

Just write one of them:

```
$("#my_element").data('data2', 'myData2Changed');
```

Or you can even do:

```
$("#my_element").data({data2: 'myData2Changed'});
```

Comment: That's not what he's trying to do.

Comment: If I do this, am I not setting a new data for my element, therefore losing all my previously stored data `data1` and `data3`?

Comment: @user765368 you don't lose any of the other data points that were set.